# django-axes is not getting the request argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I recently added `django-axes` to my Django project. It is suppose to work out the box with `django-restframework`. However, I am using `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` to handle authentication. But it should still work out the box since the only thing that is required for `django-axes` is passing Django's authentication method the request object which it does in it's source code ([line 39 and 43](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py)).

When I try to authenticate, I get this error from `django-axes`:

> axes.exceptions.AxesBackendRequestParameterRequired: AxesBackend requires a request as an argument to authenticate

Answer (score 2):

You need to add requests to the authentication function. See sample code below.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def _authenticate_user_email(self, email, password, request):

        # This is key: Pass request to the authenticate function
        self.user = authenticate(email=email, password=password, request=request)
        return self.user

    def validate(self, attrs):

        password = attrs.get('password')
        email = attrs.get('email')
        request = self.context.get('request')   # <<=== Grab request

        self.user = self._authenticate_user_email(email, password, request)

        # All error handling should be done by this code line 

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data = {}
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        return data
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from authy.serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from authy.views import MyTokenObtainPairView

url(r'^/auth/api/token/$', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

It is also worth mentioning that the simple jwt lib uses the **authenticate** function, however it does not pass the request parameter. Therefore you need call authenticate, get_token and return data object yourself.

In addition, if you have extended the AbstractBaseUser model of django. And set the **USERNAME_FIELD**. Then use the param username instead of email. E.g: **authenticate**(*username*=email, password=password, request=request)

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082673/lukik! I added a couple of details I found was missing upon fixing this myself.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. It makes the example more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from axes.backends import AxesBackend


class MyBackend(AxesBackend)
    def authenticate(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if request:
            return super().authenticate(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> This would skip the AxesBackend in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS if the request is unset and would weaken your security setup.

source: https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/issues/478